# Typescript: Include keys in function response based on argument

Tags: typescript

Working on typing an SDK for a Rest API. The API has an embed request param that will join additional resources and append them to the response. I am wondering with Typescript if there is a way to extract these embed params when creating the return type for `getImage`. I've gotten close with Generics, but not as clean as I was hoping. Here's a contrived example, but I'm looking for a solution that could be applied to numerous methods with various embed options each. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

```
interface Type {
  ext: string
}
interface User {
  id: number
  name: string
}
interface Image {
  id: number
  name: string
}

function getImage(id: number, embed?: string | string[]) {
  // make API request
}
```

With no embeds

```
getImage(1)

{
  id: 1,
  name: 'my-image'
}
```

With one embed

```
getImage(1, 'type')

{
  id: 1,
  name: 'my-image',
  type: {
    ext: '.png'
  }
}
```

With array of embeds

```
getImage(1, ['type', 'user])

{
  id: 1,
  name: 'my-image',
  type: {
    ext: '.png'
  },
  user: {
    id: 2,
    name: 'John Doe'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Next example might help you:

```js
interface Type {
    ext: string
}

interface User {
    id: number
    name: string
}

interface Image {
    id: number
    name: string
}


type ArrayValues<T extends ReadonlyArray<string>> = T[number]
type Ext<T extends string> = `.${T}`;

type Two<T extends string> = User & {
    [P in T]: {
        ext: Ext<'png'>
    }
}

type Three<T extends ReadonlyArray<string>> = {
    [P in ArrayValues<T>]: P extends 'type' ? {
        ext: Ext<'png'>
    } : User
}

/**
 * FUnction overloading is your best friend in such kind of situations
 */
function getImage<T extends number, U extends ReadonlyArray<string>>(id: T, embed: U): Three<U>
function getImage<T extends number, U extends string>(id: T, embed: U): Two<U>
function getImage<T extends number>(id: T): User
function getImage(id: number, embed?: string | ReadonlyArray<string>) {
    return {} as any
}


const result1 = getImage(1)
// {
//   id: 1,
//   name: 'my-image'
// }

const result2 = getImage(1, 'type')


// {
//   id: 1,
//   name: 'my-image',
//   type: {
//     ext: '.png'
//   }
// }

// Used `as const` to help TS narrow types
const result3 = getImage(1, ['type', 'user'] as const)


// {
//   id: 1,
//   name: 'my-image',
//   type: {
//     ext: '.png'
//   },
//   user: {
//     id: 2,
//     name: 'John Doe'
//   }
// }
```

[Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoE8AOKDeAoZQ5CADzAC5kBnMKUAczwF889RJZEUBVK6ZfEWTAAJpRABXALYAjaASIg4UiJRp0QjFm3DR4SZAEkpcergWFR46XKgXkSlWtoNmrMFhQBBKFDjoANTgAGwkIKgAeVGIyCBARKmQAJQg4EQB7EGD0Hz90CPUGAD4i5ABeNABtSVloAF08D2xkAFEyKJjIeMTCzVKKgAMAOgASHFQmAYBud080AHd0jtIuhOoXPvLkXn4AMgF7SoAFYRA0OspBISIVyjawCIByTE1HovsWbSaUVAALKAgEGWsW6yVSGSyOV8-gKG3oJS2V0Ix1OyFy-iCoXCUSKF2QJxWcTWj2%20j2QAH4DtcbmQ7u1nq93kImMhKDs7NoYBIQAgwMBMsgzGBjKYgdFCaCarYADTbTpExIpNKZbLo-K9eFFAAUVjQsogtTE2wAlJQ-gCgdx3lyeXyBUKRWZgatElLoLLuPLQRrtbrUPrDWzTQslla8Dbefyzg6TE7xSC1m6oL6jahg%20zw9zI-aIMLYxAdUakwG5CJyc4NPRkAAfMHKyFq2GVorGqlEAFgCRQM44FlwRJwEDoNysBCZGjIAFUCTBMAARi2MdFWrnxrwAHp1wdN0RdXPpRut4RHKpkI8pOgALTAfOPQ-IbRjkATqczsAAJkXucdBf3Z9Ja6sDu%20A7pYRr7vex7KKe55XjeoqPAeoHIN8lyQTSFBnkMLz0HeyEsDuj7jmAk7hG%20ADMX55suf6VCSniIWeEh8FAjx1Mg-bIE%20NCAfeIFHsI4FIQJJ6ULB163sJRCoduAmELcWE4XhAlMFJhDMdAaHIWBlDvmpijQWJABS6S-GcAAi6QQMpRAEVuTBAA)

> but I'm looking for a solution that could be applied to numerous methods with various embed options each. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

To make it possible, you should change a bit your data structure.
For example, in array `['type','user']` you handle `type` not in the same way as `user`.